# How to change a vertical string to a horizontal string in python?

Tags: python, string, short

I have tried using those script but they don't work. (x is a vertical variable)

```
print "".join(x.split())
```

and

```
x.replace("\n", "")
```

(try to explain your answer if you can)
SAMPLE INPUT-OUTPUT:
Input:

- H
- E
- L
- L
- O

Output:
HELLO ABC

Comment: `input` is a `builtins` function .Don't name your variable as `input`.

Comment: hey give this guy a break, he's a new contributor

Comment: OP it would be better /great if you explain your problem or what you are trying to achive more precisely

Comment: The ``print`` without parentheses indicates that you are using Python 2. Please strongly consider using Python 3 instead, since Python 2 has reached its end of life. Are you looking for a solution that works in Python 2, or are you fine with Python 3 solutions as well?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some sample input, as well as the current output of your approach and the desired output.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thanks for your advice. I already edit the question

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your advice. I already edited the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input=(a\nb\nc\nd\nA\nB\nC\n) #<---Vertical text

result=input.replace("\n", "") #Convert the vertical text to horizontal text

print(result) #Print the horizontal text
```

Output:
abcABC

100% working for my program

Answer (score 2):

to convert vertical string to Horizontal string in pY3 just add the following to your end command in the print statement of op.

```
#when i is your vertical op
#add (",end='')
for i in s1:
    print(i, end='')
```

It will convert to Horizontal op.

Answer (score 0):

Convert horizontal to vertical:
You just need to enter a  newline character (`\n`) after every character in the string.

```
s1 = "abcd1234" # some horizontal string
s2 = "" # another string: we will use this to store verical form of s1
for i in s1:
    s2 = s2 + i + '\n'
```

Convert vertical to horizontal:
You just need to remove newline character (`\n`) after every character in the string.

```
s1 = "a\nb\nc\nd\n1\n2\n3\n4\n" # some horizontal string
s2 = "" # another string: we will use this to store horizontal form of s1
for i in s1:
if i != '\\n':
    s2 = s2 + i + '\n'
```

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're trying to say

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA but the question did'nt specify the version of python used. However, got rid of the print statement to be on the safer side (also corrected the code).

Comment: I'm not trying to convert horizontal string to vertical strings, but I'm trying the opposite.(vertical>horizontal)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA ``print(s)`` (as originally used in this answer) is not an error in Python 2. In fact, it will produce the same output in Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @Suyash there is still an error even though I tried using your script( (IndentationError: expected an indented block) in "if i != '\\n':")